# On click with an element that has been added to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add a delete button dynamically to the page once the user uploads an image.

```
$('.galleryImage .delete').bind('click', function() {

//do delete

}
```

The above does not work.

As I understand it, it's because the delete button is added to the page after creation.

I've tried

```
$('body').on('click', '.galleryImage .delete', function() {
```

But this only works with jquery 1.7+ and I need to use 1.6.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Spend some more time with the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to use in jQuery 1.6 so you can use `.delegate()` event handling.

```
$('.galleryImage').delegate('.delete', 'click', function() {
```

but would be better if you use jquery 1.7

and `.on()` event handler

```
$('.galleryImage').on('click', '.delete',function() {
```

#### According to comment

if `.galleryImage` is dynamically added then you should use a `Static-element` that is container of `.galleryImage`, that means the container should not dynamic.

Comment: The `.delete` (and, possibly, `.galleryImage`) element is the one that's dynamically added to the page, so your code is backwards. It should be (assuming `.galleryImage` is **not** dynamically added): `$('.galleryImage').delegate('.delete', 'click', function() {...});`

Comment: The delegate does not work :(

Comment: .galleryImage is dynamically added

Comment: Perfect! Will accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `delegate()`:

```
$('.galleryImage').delegate('.delete', 'click', function() {
    //do delete
}
```

Or use `on()` with a delegated selector if you are using jQuery 1.7+:

```
$('.galleryImage').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    //do delete
}
```

If the `.galleryImage` element is also dynamically added, you should use the selector which relates to the nearest non-dynamic element.

**Do not use `live()`!** It is slow, outdated and deprecated.

Comment: Yes it does. Did you read my answer?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `on` use `delegate` or `live` methods

http://api.jquery.com/live/
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/